# Anyone knows wcout supports multibyte or unicode?

Tags: visual-c++, stl

Anyone knows whether wcout supports multibyte or unicode characters?
Specifilly under Visual c++ environment?

Answer (score -1):

wcout is an object of class wostream, which is similar to ostream, but handles wchar_t wide (2-byte) characters. So the answer to the 1st question is that wcout does not support multibyte characters. The short answer to the 2nd question is that wcout supports Unicode, but the long answer is a little more involved since wide characters and Unicode are two different things, it just happens that wide characters are "wide enough" for most Unicode uses.

The best description of what Unicode really is can be found in this excellent article:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

More on Unicode vs wide characters:

http://prog.eskosoft.com/2007/01/13/19